# How to get the body of a POST (C#)

Tags: visual-studio, api, post

I am trying to get the body of a post for a program I am creating in visual studio but I am unsure how to?

I am trying to get the body from this:

POST https://userpresence.xboxlive.com/users/batch?level=all HTTP/1.1
x-xbl-contract-version: 3
Accept-Encoding: gzip; q=1.0, deflate; q=0.5, identity; q=0.1
x-xbl-contentrestrictions:
Signature:
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache
Accept: application/json
X-XblCorrelationId: eff0cf2a-42a7-4580-9ade-a77b106ea83a
PRAGMA: no-cache
Accept-Language: en-US, en
Authorization:
Content-Length: 42
Content-Type: application/json
Host: userpresence.xboxlive.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"users":[2535445967857050],"level":"all"}

Comment: Are you trying to add a body to a post request to send to that endpoint, or are you trying to read a body from a post request posted to your server (I guess the former - it doesn't really seem like xboxlive.com would you your server).

Comment: Its a part of xbox api tool, I am trying to read the post's body after its posted, it responds with the device id. I just cant figure out on how to add it to the tool since its a post

Comment: Usually you just deserialize the (json) content from the response. I guess I don't understand how you are using this api tool.